# Use ? (question mark) instead of / with Slim Framework

Tags: php, url, slim

I'm just trying to understand how to use the question mark with a URL like :

```
http://localhost/AllOfCats/index.php?m=something
```

The way I was trying :

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
     $req = $app->request(); $m= $req->get('m');
     echo "GET route : $m"; });
```

But sadly it didn't work. Do you have any idea why?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you get the GET variables when you use var_dump($_GET); ?  Not that this is the preferred method, but making sure that your web server is passing along properly.

Comment: The docs here: http://docs.slimframework.com/#Request-Overview show the way to get the request object isn't through a function call. So you should just be able to do $app->request->get( 'm' );

Comment: Hope you didn't miss `$app->run();`

Answer (score 1):

I set up the application and tested it and it works okay. Make sure that you have your app set up in your application correctly. Your app should look something like this. Make sure you didn't miss boiler plate code for setting up slim and running the application.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->get('/', function() use ($app) {
    $req = $app->request(); $m= $req->get('m');
    echo "GET route : $m"; });

$app->run();
```